# Keywords on rows to multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to parse a free form text(which is in a column) with a join expression on some keywords and I am not able to get the results I am expecting. Trying to figure out if I can catch the unknowns.

**I am trying to write this query in BigQuery**, but there is no SQl Fiddle for that so I am posting in MSSql for now.

Here I have shown some sample data in the SQL Fiddle link below, but the city_lookup table has 100s of rows because there are multiple cities in a state. The free form text can contain multiple keywords which can contain cities from the lookup table(city_lookup) and for every such occurrence, we need to record the visited state of the user. For example if the freeform text contains two cities, I should be able to write the output as two different rows with each city visited, for the same user. I am able to get this work with the query that I wrote(below), but I am also hoping to catch the rows that don't have an associated city in the city lookup table(such as Oregon). Can someone please advise how to achieve this?

DDL

```
create table city_lookup(city varchar(50), state varchar(50));
insert into city_lookup values('dallas', 'texas');
insert into city_lookup values('austin', 'texas');
insert into city_lookup values('phoenix', 'arizona');
insert into city_lookup values('tuscon', 'arizona');
insert into city_lookup values('fresno', 'california');
insert into city_lookup values('monterey', 'california');

create table log_cities
(user_id int, visited_log varchar(512));

INSERT INTO log_cities values(123, 'This user was in dallas also probably in monterey');
INSERT INTO log_cities values(234, 'Logged: visisted tuscon');
INSERT INTO log_cities values(456, 'In March she visited texas, austin');
INSERT INTO log_cities values(567, 'He was probably here in phoenix and austin');
INSERT INTO log_cities values(999, 'He was probably here in oregon');
```

Query

```
SELECT user_id,
       state,
       visited_log
FROM city_lookup c
 JOIN log_cities l ON l.visited_log LIKE CONCAT('%', c.city, '%')
ORDER BY user_id, state
```

Actual Answer

```
user_id    state            visited_log
123       california    This user was in dallas also probably in monterey
123       texas         This user was in dallas also probably in monterey
234       arizona       Logged: visisted tuscon
456       texas         In March she visited texas, austin
567       arizona       He was probably here in phoenix and austin
567       texas         He was probably here in phoenix and austin
```

Expected Answer

```
user_id    state            visited_log
123       california    This user was in dallas also probably in monterey
123       texas         This user was in dallas also probably in monterey
234       arizona       Logged: visisted tuscon
456       texas         In March she visited texas, austin
567       arizona       He was probably here in phoenix and austin
567       texas         He was probably here in phoenix and austin
999       NULL          He was probably here in oregon
```

As you can see I am unable to check conditions where is no match such as the last row shown here above. Reason being,  I am trying to catch scenarios where I have an unmapped city(in my free form text) which needs to be accounted for in city_lookup table.

```
999      NULL           He was probably here in oregon
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and could really use some help.

**SQL Fiddle Link**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca253/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT user_id, state, visited_log
FROM log_cities l LEFT JOIN
     city_lookup c 
     ON l.visited_log LIKE CONCAT('%', c.city, '%')
ORDER BY user_id, state;
```

This will work in SQL Server.  BigQuery sometimes has problems with `LEFT JOIN`s with inequalities.  This might work:

```
SELECT l.*,
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(c.city)
        FROM city_lookup cl
        WHERE l.visited_log LIKE CONCAT('%', c.city, '%')
       ) as cities
FROM log_cities;
```

In BQ, having the results in an array is probably more useful than in separate rows.  However, you can unnest the array.

EDIT:

A version that will work is:

```
WITH lc AS (
      SELECT user_id, state, visited_log
      FROM log_cities l JOIN
           city_lookup c 
           ON l.visited_log LIKE CONCAT('%', c.city, '%')
     )
SELECT lc.*
FROM lc
UNION ALL
SELECT l.user_id, NULL, l.visited_log
FROM log_cities l
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM lc
                  WHERE lc.user_id = l.user_id
                 )
ORDER BY user_id, state;
```

Or another alternative with arrays uses a different approach.  It compresses the cities into a regular expression, then gets a match on the cities in the string, and finally converts that back to states.  Here I'm including a complete BQ script:

```
create temporary table city_lookup(city string, state string);
insert into city_lookup values
('dallas', 'texas'), ('austin', 'texas'), ('phoenix', 'arizona'), ('tuscon', 'arizona'), ('fresno', 'california'), ('monterey', 'california');

create temporary table log_cities
(user_id int, visited_log string);

INSERT INTO log_cities values
(123, 'This user was in dallas also probably in monterey'),
(234, 'Logged: visisted tuscon'),
(456, 'In March she visited texas, austin'),
(567, 'He was probably here in phoenix and austin'),
(999, 'He was probably here in oregon');


SELECT l.*,
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(c2.state)
        FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(l.visited_log, c.cities_pattern)) city JOIN
             city_lookup c2
             USING (city)
       ) as states
FROM log_cities l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT STRING_AGG(c.city, '|') as cities_pattern
      FROM city_lookup c 
     ) c;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you. Running into issues when I test running your query that you shared. It is complaining again about the LEFT OUTER JOIN, "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."                                                                                                                         
        SELECT l.*,
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(cl.city)
        FROM city_lookup cl
        WHERE l.visited_log LIKE CONCAT('%', cl.city, '%')
       ) as cities
FROM log_cities;

Comment: @peoppa . . . Does the array version have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I've posted the query that I used in my comment above. Seems to be having the same issue. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: WITH lc AS (
      SELECT user_id, state, visited_log
      FROM twttr-itbi-gcp-prod.itbi_userservices_dev.city_log l JOIN
           twttr-itbi-gcp-prod.itbi_userservices_dev.lookup c 
           ON regexp_contains(lower(CONCAT('#', l.visited_log, '#')) , lower(concat( '[^a-zA-Z]', c.city, '[^a-zA-Z]' )))
     )
SELECT lc.*
FROM lc
UNION ALL
SELECT l.user_id, NULL, l.visited_log
FROM twttr-itbi-gcp-prod.itbi_userservices_dev.city_log l
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM lc
                  WHERE lc.user_id = l.user_id
                 )
ORDER BY user_id, state;

Comment: I modified the version so use REGEXP_CONTAINS because of a regex requirement. Absolute mastery of SQL and beautiful use of NOT EXISTS in your answer Gordon! Thank you very much. I will let you know if I have any other questions or comments here.

Comment: sincerely apologize. Of course this is the answer, I may have accidentally double clicked instead of a single click.

Answer (score 1):

you need to select from log_cities table and `left join` with your lookup table:

```
SELECT user_id,
       state,
       visited_log
FROM log_cities l
LEFT JOIN city_lookup c ON l.visited_log LIKE CONCAT('%', c.city, '%')
ORDER BY user_id, state
```

Comment: Thank you eshirvana, the left join is problematic in BigQuery, it complains about inequalities. However, it does work on MsSQL as I have tried that before, so I do appreciate your answer.